# Acumatica: cannot clear PropertyException from data grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, acumatica

I have a data grid that can be editable and user can add a record.
User can edit only one property - Type of the record and all the rest of properties - the code sets up.
I need to prevent duplication and throw property exception, but I cannot remove this error afterwards.
My validation is raised in Row Selected:

```
 public virtual void MPEmployeeTerminationItem_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
```

The of validation method:

```
  private bool ValidateDuplication(PXCache cache, MPEmployeeTerminationOtherItem row, int validNumberOfRecords)
    {
        bool isValid = OtherTerminationPayments.Select().FirstTableItems.Count(r => r.PaymentType == row.PaymentType) <= validNumberOfRecords && this.IsValidWeeklySalary;
        if (!isValid)
        {

            cache.RaiseExceptionHandling(typeof(MPEmployeeTerminationOtherItem.paymentType).Name, row, row.PaymentType, 
                new PXSetPropertyException(PXMessages.LocalizeFormat($"Duplication payment type ({row.PaymentType}) is not allowed.")) );
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var item in OtherTerminationPayments.Select().FirstTableItems)
            {
                cache.RaiseExceptionHandling(typeof(MPEmployeeTerminationOtherItem.paymentType).Name, item, item.PaymentType, null);
            }
        }

        Save.SetEnabled(isValid);
        SaveClose.SetEnabled(isValid);

        return isValid;
    }
```

The validation happens
[image]

I can clear validation when I change the type of the second record:
[image]
But it doesn't clear up the validation when I change the record type for the first record: 
[image]
The debugging shows that the record is valid and line that should remove the error:

```
 cache.RaiseExceptionHandling(typeof(MPEmployeeTerminationOtherItem.paymentType).Name, item, item.PaymentType, null);
```

runs last, however, the validation still appears as in the screenshot::
[image]
Maybe I need to run the validation in another event handler or my validation code is wrong?

Suggestion with

```
PXUIFieldAttribute.SetError<MPEmployeeTerminationOtherItem.paymentType>(cache, sameRow, isError ? "Error message" : null);
```

My code:

```
 public virtual void MPEmployeeTerminationOtherItem_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        var row = e.Row as MPEmployeeTerminationOtherItem;
        if (row == null) return;
        HandleOtherTerminationItemRowFields(cache, row);
        PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<MPEmployeeTerminationOtherItem.overrideAmount>(cache, row, row.IsOverride == true);

        bool isNotDuplicated = ValidateDuplicationOtherTermination(row);
        bool isPaymentTypeValid = ValidateOtherPaymentPaymentType(row);

        PXUIFieldAttribute.SetError<MPEmployeeTerminationOtherItem.paymentType>(cache, row, isNotDuplicated && isPaymentTypeValid ?
            null : "Duplicated or empty Payment Type is not allowed.");
        Save.SetEnabled(isNotDuplicated && isPaymentTypeValid);
        SaveClose.SetEnabled(isNotDuplicated && isPaymentTypeValid);
    }
```

Doesn't really work because this validation error removes the value from the Payment Type like this:

[image]
whereas debugger shows me the value of  Payment Type as previous one.
As a result I have validation exception:
[image]
Payment type not set through UI, but it exists in the cache.
Could we prevent this reset of Payment Type while validation?

I will appreciate any help or advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:
It was OK in **row selected**:

```
 public virtual void MPEmployeeTerminationOtherItem_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        var row = e.Row as MPEmployeeTerminationOtherItem;
        if (row == null) return;
        ValidateTerminationOtherPayments(cache, row);
    }
```

But we have to notify the framework that it needs to run and update validation for ALL records:

```
  public virtual void MPEmployeeTerminationOtherItem_PaymentType_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        var row = e.Row as MPEmployeeTerminationOtherItem;
        if (row.IsNull()) return;

        OtherTerminationPayments.View.RequestRefresh();//this line needs to check validation for all MPEmployeeTerminationOtherItems and update status of PaymentType if it is valid or not

    }
```

Should update the framework also after deletion:

```
protected virtual void MPEmployeeTerminationOtherItem_RowDeleted(PXCache cache, PXRowDeletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var row = e.Row as MPEmployeeTerminationOtherItem;
        if (row.IsNull()) return;
        OtherTerminationPayments.View.RequestRefresh();//this line needs to check validation for all MPEmployeeTerminationOtherItems and update status of PaymentType if it is valid or not
    }
```

That is the trick!

Answer (score 0):

The pattern looks good but by reading the code it is not clear-cut that the error gets cleared on the same object. I would recommend refactoring that method to make sure the error is cleared on the same object it was set.

```
bool isError = [condition];
MPEmployeeTerminationOtherItem sameRow = [make sure you call clear on the same object];

PXUIFieldAttribute.SetError<MPEmployeeTerminationOtherItem.paymentType>(cache, sameRow, isError ? "Error message" : null);
```

Comment: This is my problem that I need to clear error from ALL rows in the grid, because the second row is the original duplication, but I changed the first row and there is no error anymore and it should pass validation. I run through ALL record to clear the errors from ALL records (to be sure), but it doesn't work. It doesn't clear it from the second record. Save button enabled, means the method works as expected. Do I need to clear it from the cache.Inserted?

Comment: Maybe I can create an error on the grid level and not on the row level? This may resolve my problem.

Comment: There's no error on grid level, it looks like you're setting the error at the field level (payment type) instead of the row level. I have doubts about what your code is doing because of that loop. That's why I suggest you test on the 'same row' first to confirm that clearing the error works as expected. Ideally you would set the error only on the Row received as parameter to RowSelected.

Comment: This doesn't work. I'm updating my question with details.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? Do you mean the error never gets cleared?  Even when you debugged it to make sure the condition 'isNotDuplicated && isPaymentTypeValid' value changes from 'false' to 'true'?

Comment: "Doesn't really work because this validation error removes the value from the Payment Type like this", that's a behavior of the selector usually, if you set ValidateValue=False it won't do that. When using SetError you can also add a 4th parameter which is the error value (string), this might yield the behavior you desire. Try: PXUIFieldAttribute.SetError<MPEmployeeTerminationOtherItem.paymentType>(cache, row, isNotDuplicated && isPaymentTypeValid ?
            null : "Duplicated or empty Payment Type is not allowed.", row.PaymentType)

Comment: This change PXUIFieldAttribute.SetError<MPEmployeeTerminationOtherItem.paymentType>(cache, row, isNotDuplicated && isPaymentTypeValid ? null : "Duplicated or empty Payment Type is not allowed.", row.PaymentType) 
keeps the PaymentType in the UI, but validation error isn't removed from GUI even when PaymentType changed and second record removed.

Comment: Can you debug to make sure it does callback? With CommitChanges=True property on the UI fields that change.

Comment: Without OtherTerminationPayments.View.RequestRefresh() it only recognize the current row and ignores other. It works perfect with  RequestRefresh().
Thank you for your efforts!

Comment: You had the unfortunate experience to encounter a refresh bug. Typically that isn't required to update the UI.